# JS & CSS Contact Form With SMTP

Tags: javascript, css, forms, smtp

I'm editing a contact form.  It's very close to running properly.  It appears like I have a small mistake that prevents the form from submitting properly.  When properly submitted, a pop up box should show, and the form should send the message.  Neither of those are happening.  What could I be doing wrong?  Thanks!

https://SiteEditing.cc/C-F-ARC-9-2023/c-f.html

Once I get the form running properly, I want my radio question to be a hidden honeypot question.

```js
/* SmtpJS.com - v3.0.0 */
var Email = { send: function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e) { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a); Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }, ajaxPost: function (e, n, t) { var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e); a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), a.onload = function () { var e = a.responseText; null != t && t(e) }, a.send(n) }, ajax: function (e, n) { var t = Email.createCORSRequest("GET", e); t.onload = function () { var e = t.responseText; null != n && n(e) }, t.send() }, createCORSRequest: function (e, n) { var t = new XMLHttpRequest; return "withCredentials" in t ? t.open(e, n, !0) : "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest ? (t = new XDomainRequest).open(e, n) : t = null, t } };
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Arial', Sans-Serif;
}

.form-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: Transparent;
    color-OFF: #C0C0C0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

form {
    background: #4169E1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 2vw 4vw;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.form-title {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #663399;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-radio {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #663399;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    /*display: none;*/
}

form input, form textarea {
    border: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: none;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #663399;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

form button {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #663399;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
    color: #663399;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: #663399;
}

::placeholder {
    color: #663399;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
        <meta name="description" content="">
        
        <meta name="author" content="">
        
        <title>SiteEditing.cc</title>
        
        <!-- Font A -->
        
        <link href="Font-A-5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="c-f.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
    <div class="form-container">
    
    <form onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false;">
        
    <h3 class="form-title">SSL SECURE CONTACT FORM <i class="fas fa-lock fa-spin"></i><br>FORM SOFTWARE STILL BEING BUILT.</h3>
    
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name?" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your Name MUST Be Added!')" Required>
    
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your VALID Email Address?" autocomplete="off" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your VALID Email Address MUST Be Added!')" Required>
    
    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Your Contact Phone Number?">
    
   <input type="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Your Message Subject?" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your Subject MUST Be Added!')" Required>
   
   <textarea id="message" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message?" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your Message MUST Be Added!')" Required></textarea>
    
    <div class="form-radio">
    <p><i class="fas fa-shield-alt fa-spin"></i> What Are You? (To Be Hidden)</p>
    
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="h-pot"><label for="radio-1"> A I &nbsp;</label>
    
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="h-pot"><label for="radio-2"> BOT &nbsp;</label>
</div>

    <button type="submit">SEND <i class="fas fa-share"></i></button>
        
    </form>
   </div>
        
    <script src="c-f.js"></script>
    
    <script>

function sendEmail () {
        Email.send({
    Host : "mail.siteediting.cc",
    Username : "smtp-test@siteediting.cc",
    Password : "-1fpzJ8h*+H3",
    Port : "587",
    To : "ijwgohlnoc@use.startmail.com",
    From : "document.GetElementById("email").value,
    Subject : "S E Contact Form Message",
    Body : "Name: " + document.GetElementById("name").value,
        + <br><br> Email: " + document.GetElementById("email").value,
        + <br><br> Phone Number: " + document.GetElementById("phone").value,
        + <br><br> Message: " + document.GetElementById("message").value,
}).then(
  message => alert(Message Sent!)
);
    }
    
    </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Form is a link, you can't submit a form and stay on the current page. That said, the form will never be submitted, as you're explicitly returning `false` after sending the message.

Comment: Console: (Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list).  I have No clue what that error means.  Also, I watched a tutor video, and when the person submitted the form, that produced a popup.  He also showed the form messages in his inbox.

Comment: Here's a link to the tutor video.  https://youtube.com/watch?v=sGQSz22U8VM

Comment: Format your code so it isn’t squished on a single line then look at the rest of the error message that will tell you what line number it occurred on.

Comment: Also: I strongly recommend finding a modern guide. There’s some boilerplate there which massively bloats the JS so that it will work on Internet Explorer 6. There’s no need for that when even IE11 is dead these days.

Comment: I also recommend not using tutorials which make you transcribe code from videos. That’s highly error prone.

Comment: Oh god. It’s worse that I though. It does explicit checks for XDomainRequest and then tries to use onload (which it doesn’t, AFAIK, support) with it.

Comment: It says line 60 column 19.

Comment: 59   function sendEmail () {
60           Email.send({
61       Host : "mail.siteediting.cc",

Comment: Your code has errors all over the place: missing quotes, quotes where there shouldn't be quotes, incorrect method names, etc.

Comment: Pointy:  Can you please make corrections for me?  Thanks!  W3 Validates the HTML.  :--)

Comment: Pointy:  Are you referring to the JS?  I need to sleep!  :--)

Answer (score 0):

Some possible issues I can see are Syntax errors, incorrect function calls, insecure password exposure. Even if this works, this is not secure.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  Email.send({
    Host: "mail.siteediting.cc",
    Username: "smtp-test@siteediting.cc",
    Password: "-1fpzJ8h*+H3",
    Port: "587",
    To: "ijwgohlnoc@use.startmail.com",
    From: document.getElementById("email").value,
    Subject: "S E Contact Form Message",
    Body: `Name: ${document.getElementById("name").value}<br><br>Email: ${document.getElementById("email").value}<br><br>Phone Number: ${document.getElementById("phone").value}<br><br>Message: ${document.getElementById("message").value}`
  }).then(
    message => alert('Message Sent!')
  );
}
```

Again: Exposing SMTP credentials in client-side JavaScript is not secure. Consider using a server-side method for email sending.

Comment: I'm also editing a Different contact form.  When getting a form running, I Won't have the password in the same file as the form.  I'm only in testing mode.  :--)

Comment: What's the JS equivalent to the below PHP code?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title']00 {
      die();